# Arithmetic Overflow on MySQL Table Even After Increasing Column Length

Tags: mysql, sql-server, math, casting, overflow

I have a linked server on  MS SQL Server which opens a MySQL Table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `postilion_data_tst` (
  `issuer` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  **`post_tran_id` bigint(12) DEFAULT '0',**
  `post_tran_cust_id` bigint(8) DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_entity_id` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `batch_nr` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_cash_req` double DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_amount_rsp` double DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_amount_req` double DEFAULT '0',
  `sink_node_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `tran_postilion_originated` double DEFAULT '0',
  `tran_completed` double DEFAULT '0',
  `message_type` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `tran_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT '',
  `tran_nr` bigint(8) DEFAULT '0',
  `system_trace_audit_nr` varchar(6) DEFAULT '',
  `rsp_code_req` varchar(2) DEFAULT '',
  `rsp_code_rsp` varchar(2) DEFAULT '',
  `sponsor_bank` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `retrieval_reference_nr` varchar(12) DEFAULT '',
  `datetime_tran_gmt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_tran_local` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_req` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_rsp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `realtime_business_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `recon_business_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_account_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT '',
  `to_account_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT '',
  `from_account_id` varchar(28) DEFAULT '',
  `to_account_id` varchar(28) DEFAULT '',
  `tran_amount_req` double DEFAULT '0',
  `tran_amount_rsp` double DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_amount_impact` double DEFAULT '0',
  `tran_cash_req` double DEFAULT '0',
  `tran_cash_rsp` double DEFAULT '0',
  `tran_currency_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT '',
  `settle_cash_rsp` double DEFAULT '0',
  `settle_currency_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT '',
  `tran_reversed` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `prev_tran_approved` double DEFAULT '0',
  `source_node_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `pan` varchar(19) DEFAULT '',
  `card_seq_nr` varchar(3) DEFAULT '',
  `expiry_date` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `terminal_id` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `terminal_owner` varchar(25) DEFAULT '',
  `merchant_type` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `card_acceptor_name_loc` varchar(40) DEFAULT '',
  `totals_group` varchar(12) DEFAULT '',
  `card_product` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `region` varchar(3) DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I run the following insert statement and it fails with

"Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The statement has been terminated."

```
INSERT INTO postilion_data_tst (issuer,  
post_tran_id, 
post_tran_cust_id, 
settle_entity_id,
batch_nr, 
settle_cash_req, 
settle_amount_rsp, 
settle_amount_req, 
sink_node_name, 
tran_postilion_originated, 
.
.
.

SELECT 
'Ecobank',
**2220920095,** 
dbo.post_tran_tab.post_tran_cust_id,
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_entity_id,
dbo.post_tran_tab.batch_nr, 
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_cash_req, 
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_amount_rsp, 
...
```

The script succeeds when I reduce the value being inserted into the problematic column by just character. RPlease note I had earlier increased the width of the problematic column from 8 to 12.

**PREVIOUS -   **`post_tran_id` bigint(8) DEFAULT '0',****
**CURRENT -   **`post_tran_id` bigint(12) DEFAULT '0',****

```
INSERT INTO postilion_data_tst (issuer,  
post_tran_id, 
post_tran_cust_id, 
settle_entity_id,
batch_nr, 
settle_cash_req, 
settle_amount_rsp, 
settle_amount_req, 
sink_node_name, 
tran_postilion_originated, 
.
.
.

SELECT 
'Ecobank',
**222092009,** 
dbo.post_tran_tab.post_tran_cust_id,
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_entity_id,
dbo.post_tran_tab.batch_nr, 
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_cash_req, 
dbo.post_tran_tab.settle_amount_rsp, 
...
```

What could be the problem? My thinking is that BIGINT(12) would be enough to contain 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Bigint(8) and bigint(12) is exactly the same data type. The length part of the field definition does not affect the lower and upper limits of any integer data type. The length parameter only kicks in, if the field has zero fill property set. In that case MySQL will show leading zeros if a value does not have enough digits.

MySQL documentation on [integer data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) indicate the lower and upper limits of the bigint field: -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807 respectively.

You need to determine if your data is outside of these limit or not.

Pls also note, that the error message mentions conversion to int, not to bigint. The number in the sample fits into a bigint, but will not fit into an int field.

ADDITION

When you configured your myodbc connector, you may have checked the [no bigint option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html) that converts bigint to int and this may explain the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shadow. 222092009 (length 9) fits in the column perfectly and script works but 2220920095 (length 10) does not work and returns the error.

Comment: Yes, I understood your question and attempted to provide an answer. Have you checked the myodbc connection options as suggested in the answer?

Comment: I am connecting from a SQL Server Linked Server configured. How do I check this. I am wondering whether that could really be a problem since the script works for one value but not the other.

Comment: 222092009 is lower than the upper limit of the MySQL's signed int data type, while 2220920095 is higher. Both of them are lower, than the upper limit of the signed bigint data type. Either you got the field wrong that causes the error, or somehow the bigint data type of MySQL is interpreted as int (see your own error message that talks about int and not bigint). The only reason I'm aware of that could cause such behaviour is this configuration setting of myodbc. You should be able to check out the connection properties in sql server management studio.

Comment: OK> Thanks Shadow. I finally worked around it by changing that field to data type VARCHAR(15)

Answer (score 0):

Changed datatype for that specific field to VARCHAR(15). In my case the workaround would not negetively impact application but may not fit in all cases.